# combining count(column) with count(column) in same table (MSSQL)

Tags: sql, count

I am probably missing something obvious here, but what if I wanted to combine this

```
select location, count(location)
from item
group by location
```

with this

```
select collection, count(collection)
from item
group by collection
```

in the same result set.  I just want to see how many items in each collection at each location.

EDIT: I'd like to see location as a column and collection as a row

EDIT: Looks like I'll need a PIVOT to make this happen

Comment: Yes, in SQL you'd use a pivot statement. I don't like them, though. You see, for an SQL Pivot you need to know the locations beforehand although as per database design they are supposed to be dynamic (rather then having columns called location_a, location_b, etc.) So I stay away from pivot queries and solve this on the client side with a programming language instead.

Answer (score 2):

Is it as simple as this?:

```
select location,collection, count(*)
from item
group by location,collection
```

That's certainly what sprang to mind from

> how many items in each collection at each location.

But if it's wrong, maybe you should add some sample data and expected results to your question.

Comment: So what if I wanted to convert the collection or location column into a row?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for a [`PIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) - you should be aware that `PIVOT`s are only straightforward to write if you have a fixed set of columns to produce - otherwise you have to resort to dynamic SQL.

Comment: Ah okay.  Yes, I think a PIVOT is what I am looking for.  By "fixed set of columns" do you mean I will not be able to do counts without resorting to dynamic SQL?

Comment: @Marc - I mean it's fine if you're query is always dealing with `location 1`, `location 2` and `location 3`, and no other locations. But if you want the query to work with any number of locations, you'd need dynamic SQL. Basically, any given SQL query always has a fixed "shape" - the number of columns, and the names and types of each column are always the same.

Comment: I ended up dumping this result set into Excel in order to PIVOT it easily.  I still have trouble wrapping my head around SQL PIVOTs.  I'll get it eventually.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
select location, collection, count(*)
from item
group by location, collection
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do a `UNION` between the result set like

```
select location, count(location)
from item
group by location

UNION ALL

select collection, count(collection)
from item
group by collection
```